# Where is Perl's postfix `for` syntax documented?

Tags: perl, syntax

I recently came across the following code snippet

```
$count_stuff{$_}++ for @stuff;
```

It's a pretty convenient way to use a hash to count occurrences of strings in an array for example. I understand *how* it works, but not *why* it works. I can not find the documentation for this way of using **for**.

Why does it work? And where is the documentation?

Comment: Probably for the same reason that you can use `if`, `while`, or `unless` after a statement.

Comment: Thanks. As you can tell I'm a Perl noob but the [beginner] meta tag is removed.

Comment: There is some ambiguity between the perldocs `perlfunc` `perlop` and `perlsyn`, but between the three of these you can find almost anything. N.B. `perlfunc` is searchable with the command line switch `-f` as in `perldoc -f opendir`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is documented in the "perlsyn" man page, under [Statement Modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) (which talks about the postfix syntax) and under [Foreach Loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) (which explains that "for" and "foreach" are synonyms).

Answer (score 3):

Perl has postfix variants for many of its statements. It's just that you write the keyword after the one-statement body.

You can use `if`, `unless`, etc. in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/for.html) it is documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements)
And you should read [Foreach Loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) to get answer for your question.

In short, If you you understand this well:

```
for my $item ( @array ) { print $item }
```

And know syntax of `for` and `print`:

```
LABEL for VAR (LIST) BLOCK
print LIST
```

According to the doc of [foreach](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops): `If VAR is omitted, $_ is set to each value.`
And according to the doc of [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html): `If LIST is omitted, prints $_`

So we can reduce the example above:

```
for ( @array ) { print }
```

In the postfix form it will look like this:

```
print for @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the standard Perl `for`. Takes each element and executes the body (in this case is before) with `$_` substituted with each element. It is just an alternate syntax for: `for (@array) { statements }`