# advanced perl syntax - Mojo::DOM

Tags: perl, dom, syntax, html-parsing, mojolicious

I am trying to understand some advanced (for me) perl syntax for html parsing using DOM following [this tutorial](http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2012/05/using-mojodom.html):

```
say "div days:";
say $_->text for $dom->find('div.days')->each;

say "\nspan hours:";
say $_->text for $dom->find('span.hours')->each;
```

What does this syntax mean? What kind of loop is this? Classic for construction looks like this: `for(i=0;i<10;i++){ code }` not: `{code} for (some_condition)`

Also what does "each" keyword mean in this context? Does it have something common with the [`each` Perl builtin function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) or it is specific to Mojo::DOM? I think if `each` is under Mojo::Dom it should be mentioned on the Mojo::DOM homepage. But I did not found any mention of `each` under the [methods section of their site](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm), so it must be a builtin function of Perl. But, this builtin `each` function has a completely different syntax -- how is this possible?

Another example from tutorial page

```
say "Open Times:";
say for $dom->find('div.openTime')
            ->map(sub{$_->children->each})
            ->map(sub{$_->text})
            ->each;
```

Same issue as above for [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`sub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sub.html) methods.

- Can those pieces of "Perlish" code rewritten in a more "C style" manner so I can understand it?
- Most importantly: How to list all methods their parameters and return values contained in Mojo::DOM? It must be done somehow, because I read that even for Perl there are IDEs with intellisense (autocompletion) so this IDE must know the methods return value types etc.

Comment: I answer in a full answer below, but let me stress that the reason you are not finding all of the method names is that the "missing" ones are actually methods on [Mojo::Collection](http://p3rl.org/Mojo::Collection) which is a container object for holding more than one dom object. Again see below.

Comment: If any of the answers below was helpful to you, please take the time to accept it. You can do so by clicking the check mark on the left. See [faq#howtoask] if you need help.

Answer (score 9):

```
say "Open Times:";
say for $dom->find('div.openTime')
            ->map(sub{$_->children->each})
            ->map(sub{$_->text})
            ->each;
```

All those keywords (`find`, `map`, `each`) are actually **not keywords** but methods from Mojo::DOM. You can recognize them by the `->` operator.

In this case, several [methods have been chained together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). That is only possible if each of them returns its object (in this example it's `$dom`) again. This kind of chaining is often used in JavaScript, especially with modern frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It makes the code easy to read and saves operations.

Basically, you apply several transactions in a chain.

1. [`find`](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm#find) all elements 'div.openTime'
2. [`map`](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/Collection.pm#map) ( do stuff with each of ) them with a given sub (this is an actual Perl `sub`):

   1. get all [`children`](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm#children) of the current element as a collection
   2. and list [`each`](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/Collection.pm#each) of them (as in, return an array)
3. `map` them with a given sub:

   1. extract [`text`](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm#text) content from the element
4. and list `each` of them

All this is wrapped in a postfix `foreach` (as said by @Quentin). [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) is a feature you can load with `use features qw(say)`. It combines `print` and a newline-character.

Maybe now it's clearer what is happening here:

```
my $collection1 = $dom->find('div.oopenTime');

my $collection2 = $collection1->map(
  sub {
    my $collection = $_->children;
    return $collection->each;
  }
);

my collection3 = $collection2->map(
  sub {
    return $_->text;
  }
);

foreach my $text ($collection3) {
  say $text;
}
```

---

IDEs that provide autocompletion will usually scan the code in question to know the methods an object has. Take a look at [How do I list available methods on a given object or package in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910430/how-do-i-list-available-methods-on-a-given-object-or-package-in-perl) or read the code of the module. Even better: **read the documentation**.

Answer (score 5):

> What does this syntax mean, what is going on here ?

It is a [postfix for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281398/where-is-perls-postfix-for-syntax-documented).

```
for (@foo) {
    say $_
}
```

can be written as

```
say $_ for @foo;
```

> Also what does "each" keyword mean in this context

It is [a method on the object](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.44/lib/Mojo/Collection.pm#each). It returns a list of things in the Mojo::Collection.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the other answers have explained what I wrote in my tutorial post. That said I wanted to add that I have come to grips with another useful method in Mojo::DOM (actually in the Mojo::Collection class) called [`pluck`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection#pluck). This method reduces the visual complexity of

```
->map(sub{$_->text})
```

to

```
->pluck('text')
```

<s>Further I have noticed that at least a few of my `each` calls were extraneous and that a Mojo::Collection used in a list context will "Do What I Mean" and `each` automagically.</s>
Edit: I checked this and in fact when used as a string the elements are joined with a newline. As this isn't exactly what I want, I have returned my `each` calls.

All that said here is how I might write that same tutorial script now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(<<'HTML');
<div class="box notranslate" id="venueHours">
<h5 class="translate">Hours</h5>
<div class="status closed">Currently closed</div>
<div class="hours">
  <div class="timespan">
    <div class="openTime">
      <div class="days">Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Sat</div>
      <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–6:00 PM</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timespan">
    <div class="openTime">
      <div class="days">Fri</div>
      <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–9:00 PM</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timespan">
      <div class="openTime">
        <div class="days">Sun</div>
        <span class="hours"> 10:00 AM–5:00 PM</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
HTML

say "div days:";
say for $dom->find('div.days')->pluck('text')->each;

say "\nspan hours:";
say for $dom->find('span.hours')->pluck('text')->each;

say "\nOpen Times:";
say for $dom->find('div.openTime')
            ->map(sub{$_->children->each})
            ->pluck('text')
            ->each;
```

Note that I don't use `->pluck('children')` because the `children` method returns a Mojo::Collection object, meaning that the return from `pluck` would be a collection of collections. In order to flatten the structure I need to call `each` on the result of the `children` call and thus I cannot remove that particular `->map` call.

However, now I wonder if I couldn't avoid this hassle all together? Mojo::DOM has excellent support for [CSS3 selectors](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/CSS) ([w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)), and one thing I might try would be not to select the parent (`div.openTime`) directly but select its children in the selector.

```
say "\nOpen Times:";
say for $dom->find('div.openTime > *')->pluck('text')->each;
```

So there is a good lesson here: allowing the selector to give you as nearly the collection that you want saves you having to transform it later.

---

To answer your final questions:

To translate this

```
say for $dom->find('div.openTime')
            ->map(sub{$_->children->each})
            ->map(sub{$_->text})
            ->each;
```

to more C-esque Perl (though I wont take it to the `for(i=0;i<10;i++){ ... }` extreme) it might look something like

```
my @open_times = $dom->find('div.openTime')->each;

my @all_children;
foreach my $elem ( @open_times ) {
  my @children = $elem->children->each;
  push @all_children, @children;
}

my @texts;
foreach my $child ( @all_children ) {
  push @texts, $child->text;
}

foreach my $text ( @texts ) {
  print $text . "\n";
}
```

I'm sure you can see why I prefer the Mojo (object-chaining) way.

As to your second question: Mojolicious has great (if sometimes oververbose) documentation. Start [here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc) to learn about the whole system. Specifically reading about [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) and [Mojo::Collection](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Collection) should be enough to handle DOM parsing. I think part of your problem is that you didn't notice the interdependency of the DOM and Collection objects and so you mistakenly assumed that all the method calls were on DOM objects. When you read carefully you will see that some of the DOM methods (those that return might more that one result) return Collection objects, and `find` is one such method.